# how to assign a width to span dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am new to html and angularjs. Here I am trying to assign span width 
dynamically from angular js responce

```
<div class="statarea" ng-repeat="x in names">
     <div class="ratingarea">
        <div class="your-rating"><span style="width:"+{{ x.width }}+";" class="outer"></span>
        </div>
     <div class="clear"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

In my Script is

```
$http.get(url).success(function (response) {
  $scope.names = response;
});
```

my response is

```
[
 {"width":"78%"},
 {"width":"60%"},
 {"width":"50%"}
]
```

I know it is not write,but i don't have any idea..
Thanks in advance

Comment: did you tried `ng-style="x"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ngStyle](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) as other Angular built-in directives, for instance

`ng-style="{color: myColor}"`

ngStyle needs an [Expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) which evals to an object whose keys are CSS style names and values are corresponding values for those CSS keys. So in your case, you can set the width like

```
<div class="statarea" ng-repeat="x in names">
  <span ng-style="x" />
</div>
```

Or use scope variables like

```
<div class="statarea" ng-repeat="x in names">
  <span ng-style="{'width': x.width}" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your need to use ng-style. Here is your example in JSFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/2raw9xhq/2/

```
<div ng-app="" ng-init="names = [{width:'78%', 'background-color': 'green'},{width:'60%', 'background-color': 'red'},{width:'50%','background-color': 'blue'}]">
<div class="statarea" ng-repeat="x in names">
     <div class="ratingarea">
        <div class="your-rating">
            <span ng-style="x" class="outer">{{x.width}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```